# Git fetch doesn't update to latest commit

Tags: git

**Here is the scenario.**
I have a remote git repo I use to transfer a project from my home clone to various work clones. I'm the only contributor. I have deployed the script to other machines at work. There is a second contributor `<BC>` in the git log below, but it's still me. I'm just making the commit on someone else's machine.

**My typical workflow:**

1. HOME: DO WORK
2. HOME: git push TO REMOTE
3. WORK: git fetch [project]
4. WORK: git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
5. WORK: git clean -df

The basic idea of this workflow is to overwrite local clones with the remote (`reset --hard`), because it's just me doing the work. The assumption is--as long as I push after every change, then the remote should always have the most current version.

**Git logs:**

```
Home clone
* m9911ebf - (HEAD -> master, plr_generate/dev) FIX(PLRG) ... (3 months ago) <CS>

Work clone
* md63cd90 - (HEAD -> master, plr_generate/master, plr_generate/HEAD) ADD(PLRG) ... (2 days ago) <BC>
* m45d47c2 - DOCS(PLRG) ... (9 weeks ago) <CS>
* m72bfd73 - BUG(PLRG) ... (9 weeks ago) <CS>
* md13c874 - ADD(PLRG) ... (9 weeks ago) <BC>
* m9911ebf - (plr_generate/dev, dev) FIX(PLRG) ... (3 months ago) <CS>
```

As you can see, the work clone shows updates in the log; however, I can't update my home clone using my workflow (above).

**I've verified,**

- on the `master` branch on both.
- remote is showing the same project repo.

Basically, I had a workflow that worked for me, and I didn't learn more git than was necessary. Clearly, I'm missing some git concept here.

How do I update home to match the remote?

**UPDATE:**
Following the comment about git command output. They do not output any unusual errors:

```
[executed from the home clone directory]
(env) xtian@host> git fetch [project]                                    
  [user]@myremote.com's password: 
stdin: is not a tty
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), done.
From myremote.com:/path/to/[project]
   45d47c2..d63cd90  master     -> [project]/master

(env) xtian@host> git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD                                   
HEAD is now at 9911ebf FIX(PLRG) ...

(env) xtian@host> git branch                                                  
  dev
* master
```

The HEAD is at `m9911ebf` in my home clone, but I expect it to be at `md63cd90`.

Also, the last commit in the log from user `<BC>` was performed on a colleague's computer. I pushed it, and fetched to my own Work clone. I logged in remotely from home into my work machine to produced the log output you see above. This suggests to me the remote repo I'm fetching has the latest changes.

Without any particular errors, I'm thinking it's something stupid (>_<).

Comment: For step 4, you mean `git reset --hard origin/master`?

Comment: @Cratylus - not clear why that would necessarily be what they mean

Comment: "however, I can't update my home clone using my workflow (above)."  And what happens when you try?  What is the output of each command?

Comment: RE: `git reset --hard origin/master`. I've renamed my remote repo to the project name: `$ git remote -vv; [project]   [user]@[domain]:/path/to/remote/[project].git` for both _fetch_ and _push_.

Comment: `git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD` looks suspicious (though it might have worked for you). What happens if you do `get merge origin/master` from your home clone?

Comment: `(env) [1] xtian@host> git merge master \
Already up to date.`

Comment: `git merge master` and `git merge origin/master` are not the same. The former merges your local master branch into your current branch, the latter merges the master branch of the remote `origin` into your current branch. `git fetch` updates the remote branches, not your local branches.

Comment: Haha. I always thought `origin/master` was 'origin or master', because you can rename these things. (I really have to learn the syntax better, ie.` \ ` and `...`, and when to use them). When I tried `$ git merge [project]\master`, then I got `Updating m9911ebf...md63cd90 \ Fast-forward`. Solved! If you want to post that as an answer, with even just a little suggestion or link of what you think is happening, I will accept that as the answer.

Comment: @xtian git pull is essentially git fetch followed by git merge, and is the usual workflow.

Comment: @ DBK, I think I know what `fetch, reset, clean` does for me. What do you think `pull` does that's better?